# chrome: uBlock / uMatrix - change color of blocked element

Tags: chrome, browser

I am using `uBlock Origin` and `uMatrix` extensions in Chrome. When an element on a website is blocked (ie advertisment), I see just white area:

[image]

When I hover over the area, it says:

```
Request to the server has been blocked by an extension
```

Anyway, since I am using dark background, the white areas on a website are actually quite annoying.

Is it possible to somehow change the color of "blocked area" to black ?
Would this be done in `uMatrix`, or chrome itself ?

I am using Chromium Version 83.0.4103.116 on Debian 10.4